# Gantt chart without weekends

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

> **Duplicate of:**
> [How to exclude or remove weekends from ganttchart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176095/how-to-exclude-or-remove-weekends-from-ganttchart)

I'm looking to create a Gantt chart using pgfgantt that only displays certain days of the week, specifically excluding weekends or Sundays. The [closest thing I've found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341133/231989) (see full code at bottom) is now four years old and refuses to compile with errors that are completely opaque to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer in the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341133/23866) uses the key `compress calendar`. However, since version 5.0 of the `pgfgantt` package this key has been changed into `time slot unit`. See the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf) for version 5.0 (page 101-102):

> **Change History**
>
> [...]
>
> v5.0
>
> [...]
>
> Key `compress calendar` has been replaced by `time slot unit` to allow an
> additional level of compression (year).

This new key has three values: `day` (no compression, default), `month` (don't show days but only months and years) and `year` (don't show months but only years and possibly decades). The value `day` corresponds to the old `compress calendar=false`, `month` is `compress calendar=true`, and `year` did not exist in version 4.0.

The code from the previous question only accounts for the first two key values, so if you want to use that code with minimal changes then you cannot use `time slot unit=year`. For the two other option values the fix is quite straightforward: change every occurrence of `\ifgtt@compresscalendar` by `\ifgtt@timeslotunit@month` (there are four occurrences in total). Note that the final two occurrences (line 203 and 217) have a `1` at the end, so they should be replaced by `\ifgtt@timeslotunit@month1`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I assume that you will make comment to this answer in the answer to te other question.

Comment: Marvellous, thanks a bunch

Comment: @Marijin Could you 1. link my post and 2. copy the code from my post with your changes applied to it?

Comment: Oh I see my code is really long...

Comment: @HoodChatham indeed because it was long and my changes are very minor I thought it would be more concise not to copy the whole 360 lines - hopefully my post is clear enough to allow the OP and other interested readers to apply the fix.

Comment: It turns out that this messes up `\startday` in the `calendar week text` key, any suggestions on fixing that?